# Using mulitple Terraform .tfvars in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a Terraform module source repository that covers three environments - dev, test and prod. Each environment has a dedicated folder, which also contains its own terraform.tfvars file as depicted below.

[image]

In conjunction with the above, I also have an Azure Release Pipeline with three deployment Stages - Dev, Test and Prod, as also depicted below.

[image]

Not surprisingly, what I am now seeking to achieve is set up the respective pipelines for all three Stages and ensure each consumes its dedicated *.tfvars file only. How can I get round this in the pipeline Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You can define variable limited to score of specific stage:

[image]

And then just call `$(TerraformVarsFile)`.